# Azure Mobile Apps FileSync support missing in Android SDK

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

This link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-app-service-updates-november-2015/ explains Azure mobile app support for Synching Files to the app services. The examples are in .NET SDK. I am looking for the same in Android SDK and these classes seem to be missing in the Android SDK documentation available [here](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/)

Wondering how can I upload files to Azure blob storage using Azure Mobile App service. I have already created a data connection pointing to my Blog storage, however, I couldn't find a way to expose an API to create the file in blog storage other than using custom API.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrian Hall's blog about [30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 28 FILE HANDLING (V2)](https://shellmonger.com/2016/06/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-28-file-handling-v2/) mentioned as follows:

> Azure Mobile Apps has a **File Management SDK** that is in preview. It requires the ASP.NET Server SDK (so no Node support) and a .NET client (Xamarin or UWP, for example), **so no iOS native, Android native or Cordova support**.

The available code sample is talking about .NET clients. For example, [App Service Mobile sample todo list client app with images](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files).

For your requirement, you could only build your custom APIs for uploading files. Details you could follow [30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 27: FILE HANDLING (V1)](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/30/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-27-file-handling-v1/). Moreover, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/568069-azure-mobile-app) or add a issue under [Microsoft Azure Mobile Apps: Android Client SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client).

Comment: thanks a lot. That blog looks great. It looks like the offline sync for files between device and azure has to be handled

Comment: according to Microsoft, they do not plan to add this to Android SDK. https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/issues/132